# Redirect after request.send() - request is not posted, page redirects

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect

I have a basic ajax comment form with a textarea and yes/no radio object.

- If 'yes' is selected, the user's comments are posted, then
  they are taken to a new page.
- If 'no', the comments are posted and they remain on the same page.

What's happening is that the comments are not posted when users select 'yes', and the page redirects anyway.

Here's the post script:

```
    //
    flag_yesno      = getRadioValue('form_comments', 'flag_yesno');

    request.open('POST', 'process.php?t=' + new Date().getTime());
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(request.readyState == 4)
        {
            // put response text in the comment_posts div
            comment_posts.innerHTML     = request.responseText;
        }
    }

    // set up POST parameters
    var params = "&foo=" + foo + "&bar=" + bar;

    // send it on over!
    request.send(params);

    // redirect if needed
    if (flag_yesno=='yes')
    {
        window.location = '/foo.php?foo='+foo;
    }
```

Is there a way to handle the redirect after `request.send()` is fired off?  It seems like the redirect is breaking that part.

Comment: Do the redirect in the callback function that handles the request’s result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait until the call has completed. Waiting "until it's fired off" is tricky to gauge.

```
if(request.readyState == 4)
{
  if (flag_yesno == 'yes')
  {
    // redirect if needed
    window.location = '/foo.php?foo='+foo;
  } 
  else
  {
    // put response text in the comment_posts div
    comment_posts.innerHTML     = request.responseText;
  } 
}
```